# Classic Asp Date

Tags: date, asp-classic

Hey, been looking for a while but I can't seem to find any info on how to handle date in classic asp.

For now, I need a way to calculate the number of days passed in the current year. I was thinking about a simple function that would take the current date, then make another date with (day = 1, month = 1, year(now)). And finally get the datediff(day) for these two. Easy enough, but I can't figure out how to do this. Help is appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps this example can help you? https://web.archive.org/web/20211020135923/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/110398-1.shtml

Comment: Thanks. Read the article there and got exactly what I needed from it. :)

Comment: So sad that this link is stale and 4guysfromrolla.com has been hijacked by some esports outfit. Sadder still that I've been looking for references to VBScript. The content people are looking for is here: https://web.archive.org/web/20211020135923/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/110398-1.shtml

Answer (score 3):

```
DateDiff("d",DateSerial(Year(Now),1,1),Date)
```

Comment: And thanks, I came to the same conclusion myself from that article posted above, minus the Date at the end. ;)